# $3- \log_3(p) = \log_p(9)$, $p = ?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Could you please show me how to solve this problem with all the steps. I’m not sure how to do it.

$$3- \log_3(p) = \log_p(9)$$

Thanks.

Comment: is this $$3-\log_3 p=\log_p 9$$?

Comment: Yes thanks, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\log_p9=2\log_p3$ and $\log_p3=\frac{1}{\log_3p}=\frac 1x$

Then solve $3-x=\frac 2x$ which leads to $x=1,2$ and hence $$p=3,9$$

Comment: Thanks so much !

Answer (score 2):

Using the change of base formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
3- \frac{\ln p}{\ln 3} =\frac{2 \ln 3}{\ln p}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let $x=\ln p$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2-3(\ln 3 ) x +2(\ln 3)^2=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Should be a doddle from here ?

Answer (score 2):

it is equivalent to $$3-\frac{\ln(p)}{\ln(3)}=\frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(p)}$$ and multiplying by $$\ln(p)\ne 0$$
$$3\ln(p)-\frac{\ln(p)^2}{\ln(3)}=\ln(9)$$
and $$3\ln(3)\ln(p)-\ln(p)^2=2\ln(3)$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yes. I think so

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-You have $\log_p(3)=\dfrac{\log_3(3)}{\log_3(p)}$. It follows 
$$X^2-3X+2=0$$ where $X=\log_3(p)$.

You get $\log_3(p)= 1\text{ or } 2$ so $p=3\text{ or } 9$.

Comment: $9$ is also a solution no?

Comment: I have seen otherwise the statement of the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: we can rewrite all the $log$'s to base $e$, which gives $3 - \frac{\ln(p)}{\ln(3)} = \frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(p)}$.